# Why are my if, else if and else statement not working as they should be?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

When I type in `France` or `france`, a country in the array, in the input field the block of code returns `country not in our database`. I'd expect the code to return `France is a country located in Europe`.

I've tried using the `return` keyword on each conditional statement but without success. I've also read up [w3schools.com's documentation on `if`/`else` statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp).

However, I'm still unable to solve that problem. Interestingly, the `else if` statement works. I mean when I leave the input field blank and then click the button the code does return `field cannot be left blank`. I know my question will probably sound pretty basic but I'm still a beginner.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
  .then(function(response){
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(function(data){
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
    var userInputValue = userInput.value;
    var region = document.getElementById("region");
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if(userInputValue.toLowerCase() === data[i].name.toLowerCase()) {
        region.innerHTML = `${data[i].name} is a country located in ${data[i].region}`
      } else if (userInputValue === "") {
        region.innerHTML = "field cannot be left blank";
      } else {
        region.innerHTML = "country not in our database";
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>API Beginners</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="userInput">country's name</label>
    <input id="userInput" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="enter a country"><br>
    <label for="button">clik here to submit</label>
    <button id="button" type="click" name="button">click me</button>
    <div id="region"></div>

  </body>
  <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: You’ll have to `break` from the for loop, otherwise the last data in the array will dictate what your element contains

Comment: As soon as any of the first two `if` conditions evaluate to true, `for` loop should break. All you need is a `break` keyword just before the closing parenthesis of the first two `if` blocks.

Comment: Don't place all the `if else` inside the for loop, I edit your code you can see it, If you have any question just comment

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, your loop is not breaking on finding a result.  Also, worth considering doing away with the loop altogether and use the array function "find":

```
var existing = data.find(d => d.name.toLowerCase() === userInputValue.toLowerCase());
region.innerHTML = existing 
    ? `${existing.name} is a country located in ${existing.region}`
    : userInputValue === ""
        ? "field cannot be left blank"
        : "country not in our database";
```

Answer (score 4):

You’ll have to `break` from the for loop in the `if` and `else if` statements, otherwise the last data in the array will dictate what your element contains.

This code would give you the expected output:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
  .then(function(response){
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(function(data){
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
    var userInputValue = userInput.value;
    var region = document.getElementById("region");
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if(userInputValue.toLowerCase() === data[i].name.toLowerCase()) {
        region.innerHTML = `${data[i].name} is a country located in ${data[i].region}`
        break;
      } else if (userInputValue === "") {
        region.innerHTML = "field cannot be left blank";
        break;
      } else {
        region.innerHTML = "country not in our database";
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>API Beginners</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="userInput">country's name</label>
    <input id="userInput" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="enter a country"><br>
    <label for="button">clik here to submit</label>
    <button id="button" type="click" name="button">click me</button>
    <div id="region"></div>

  </body>
  <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

---

And although I would favour [Neil W's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65520798/2123530) that is much more elegant, if you want to avoid repeating useless condition you could go:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
  .then(function(response){
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(function(data){
    var userInputValue = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var region = document.getElementById("region");
    if (userInputValue === "") {
      region.innerHTML = "field cannot be left blank";
      return;
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if(userInputValue.toLowerCase() === data[i].name.toLowerCase()) {
        region.innerHTML = `${data[i].name} is a country located in ${data[i].region}`
        return;
      }
    }
    region.innerHTML = "country not in our database";
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>API Beginners</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="userInput">country's name</label>
    <input id="userInput" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="enter a country"><br>
    <label for="button">clik here to submit</label>
    <button id="button" type="click" name="button">click me</button>
    <div id="region"></div>

  </body>
  <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

This actually use `return`, as you wrote you tried it.

Comment: Hello, nice what you did but there is one thing, `region.innerHTML = "country not in our database"` it will always works, like if you have 100 countries and the user country not exists in the array the `region.innerHTML = "country not in our database"` will work 100 times, and this is bad, may be you have like animation you want to play it when the user country not exist in the database so the animation will play 100 times. Check my below code in my answer I solved it.

Comment: @TahaHalabi your code is over complicated, if you want to go this route, [Neil's answer is the one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65520798/2123530)

Comment: My code is very simple and its just a simple logic, `Neil's answer` is very good but he used some es6 function like `.find, arrowfunction` and may be the user that wrote the question is a beginner in javascript and not advanced and he only knows the basics in javascript so I write for him a simple javascript code with very simple logic that he may use it with many different examples. And if he not a beginner in Javascript he can use also `Neil's Answer` it is very good.

Comment: Sorry but I do not agree with you here, one's answer should not be limited to one's audience. If you only show beginners some beginner code they will never progress. Plus this is not what a Q&A site like SO is striving for.

Comment: I know and I was writing another answer with es6 module, we should write that two, basic and advanced but  `Neil's' wrote it before me.

Comment: but just check what I wrote for the `region.innerHTML` why we should not put it inside the `for loop`

Comment: @TahaHalabi you are still doing it in an over complicated manner if you read my edited answer.

Comment: I see your code, now it is very good and more simple than my code but also my code is not complicated it is also simple, anyone who knows the basics will understand it quickly.
Just One thing return is very good but in all the places may be the user wants to continue the function not to stop this depends on his idea and on his cases. Your answer and my answer and `Neils answer` are correct.

Comment: All our answers are correct just depends on the cases. Any question may have many different answers and all may be correct

Answer (score 2):

Your for-loop is overwriting the result on each iteration. In order to see the result, you need to break the for-loop. Something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (userInputValue.toLowerCase() === data[i].name.toLowerCase()) {
        region.innerHTML = `${data[i].name} is a country located in ${data[i].region}`
        break;
    } else if (userInputValue === "") {
        region.innerHTML = "field cannot be left blank";
        break;
    }
    region.innerHTML = "country not in our database";
}
```

But please note the the `country not in our database` section is executed on every loop, and therefore this answer does not have the best performance.

Comment: Hello, nice what you did but there is one thing, `region.innerHTML = "country not in our database"` it will always works, like if you have 100 countries and the user country not exists in the array the `region.innerHTML = "country not in our database"` will work 100 times, and this is bad, may be you have like animation you want to play it when the user country not exist in the database so the animation will play 100 times. Check my below code in my answer I solved it

Comment: You are absolutely right! I probably could have refactored the code to have that line outside the for-loop. The answer of β.εηοιτ.βε has an excellent example on how to do just that, by leveraging the return statement on the ".then" over the break statement of the for-loop.

Comment: yes. But not also use the return method, may be the user wants to continue not to stop, this depends for the user cases he should choose the best for his case. All our answers are correct just depends on the cases. Any question may have many answers and all may be correct

Comment: That is the power of the stackoverflow community; giving multiple different answers solving the same problem from different angles. We will just have to see what answer the  person who asked the question will accept, and in the meanwhile the different answers will help different users with different use cases. However, we can argue over what answer adheres to the most best practices, and therefore is the "best" answer.

Answer (score 2):

I edit your code, don't place all the `if else condition inside the for loop`, `checkuserinput === "" place it before beginning of the function which is the for loop`. Just see my code and if you have any question just comment.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("button");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
 fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
  .then(function(response){
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(function(data){
 
   var check = true;
   
   var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
   
   var userInputValue = userInput.value;
   
   var region = document.getElementById("region");
   
   if (userInputValue === "") { // First Check The User Input
        region.innerHTML = "field cannot be left blank";
   } else {
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      
        if(userInputValue.toLowerCase() == data[i].name.toLowerCase()) {
        region.innerHTML = `${data[i].name} is a country located in ${data[i].region}`;
        check = true;
        break; // Break to not continue since we get what we need
        } else {
          check = false;
        }
      }
        
        if (check == false) {
           region.innerHTML = "country not in our database";
        }
   }
    
   
   
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>API Beginners</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="userInput">country's name</label>
    <input id="userInput" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="enter a country"><br>
    <label for="button">clik here to submit</label>
    <button id="button" type="click" name="button">click me</button>
    <div id="region"></div>

  </body>
  <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Offering you my comments too then: 1. you have quite a lot of inconsistencies in your indentation, although indentation does not matter that much in Javascript, it is best not to show that kind of bad practice to beginners.

Comment: 2. I really don't see the use of the counter, it makes your code really complex, because you are ultimately not using it, just use a boolean to indicate that you found the country in the loop: it generate less processing and would allocate less memory)

Comment: 3. Although I do get the fact that, for some reason that don't appeal to me some coding standard are trying to keep an unique return point in a function, please mind that you are keeping yourself away from useful refactoring patterns like [Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses](https://refactoring.guru/replace-nested-conditional-with-guard-clauses)

Comment: Hello, Instead of the counter yes we can use the boolean, it will be better and more simple. Thanks I will edit the answer